# RSA key pair is not allowing me to authenticate to my backup server

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-keys, public-key

I have a server that authenticates SSH through RSA key pairs. Yesterday my rsync backup worked successfully I know this because of log files:

```
/var/log/backups_log$ ls -l
total 815536
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139244471 Jul 26 20:02 2019-07-26_backup_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139076680 Jul 27 20:01 2019-07-27_backup_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139197173 Jul 28 20:01 2019-07-28_backup_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139249372 Jul 29 20:02 2019-07-29_backup_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141445775 Jul 30 20:11 2019-07-30_backup_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136870570 Jul 31 20:06 2019-07-31_backup_log.log
```

Today when I'm trying to SSH into my backup server I'm getting an error that looks like this:

```
ssh -p50683 10.0.1.41
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On the backup server I get the following error from the `auth.log` file:

```
~/.ssh$ tail -f -n0 /var/log/auth.log                                                                                         
Aug  1 12:43:03 Hljoo sshd[666]: Connection from 10.0.1.68 port 53690 on 10.0.1.41 port 50683                                                   
Aug  1 12:43:03 Hljoo sshd[666]: User root not allowed because account is locked                                                                
Aug  1 12:43:03 Hljoo sshd[666]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]                                                            
Aug  1 12:43:03 Hljoo sshd[666]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.68 port 53690 [preauth]
```

You'd think it would be because the account is locked, but I also get the error when attempting to login to an account that is authorized, but isn't root:

```
~/.ssh$ tail -f -n0 /var/log/auth.log                                                                                         
Aug  1 12:44:00 Hljoo sshd[671]: Connection from 10.0.1.68 port 53704 on 10.0.1.41 port 50683                                                   
Aug  1 12:44:00 Hljoo sshd[671]: Invalid user username from 10.0.1.68                                                                      
Aug  1 12:44:00 Hljoo sshd[671]: input_userauth_request: invalid user username [preauth]                                                   
Aug  1 12:44:00 Hljoo sshd[671]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.68 port 53704 [preauth]
```

Now comes the fun part. I figured maybe it had something to do with my RSA pairs, so I regenerated them successfully and transferred the keys over to my backup server. However, after doing so I get the same error. Incase you need it, here's my configuration file:

```
# Package generated configuration file                                                                                                              
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details                                                                                                        

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for                                                                                                       
Port 50683                                                                                                                                          
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to                                                                        
#ListenAddress ::                                                                                                                                   
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                              
Protocol 2                                                                                                                                          
# HostKeys for protocol version 2                                                                                                                   
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key                                                                                                                   
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key                                                                                                                   
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key                                                                                                                 
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key                                                                                                               
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security                                                                                                     
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes                                                                                                                          

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key                                                                                               
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600                                                                                                                        
ServerKeyBits 1024                                                                                                                                  

# Logging                                                                                                                                           
SyslogFacility AUTH                                                                                                                                 
LogLevel VERBOSE                                                                                                                                    

# Authentication:                                                                                                                                   
LoginGraceTime 120                                                                                                                                  
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password                                                                                                                   
StrictModes yes  
RSAAuthentication yes                                                                                                                               
PubkeyAuthentication yes                                                                                                                            
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys                                                                                                          

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files                                                                                               
IgnoreRhosts yes                                                                                                                                    
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts                                                                             
RhostsRSAAuthentication no                                                                                                                          
# similar for protocol version 2                                                                                                                    
HostbasedAuthentication no                                                                                                                          
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication                                                                       
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes                                                                                                                           

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)                                                                                        
PermitEmptyPasswords no                                                                                                                             
MaxAuthTries 3                                                                                                                                      

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with                                                                          
# some PAM modules and threads)                                                                                                                     
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no                                                                                                                  

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords                                                                                            
PasswordAuthentication no                                                                                                                           

# Kerberos options                                                                                                                                  
#KerberosAuthentication no                                                                                                                          
#KerberosGetAFSToken no                                                                                                                             
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes                                                                                                                          
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes        
# GSSAPI options                                                                                                                                    
#GSSAPIAuthentication no                                                                                                                            
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes                                                                                                                       

X11Forwarding no                                                                                                                                    
X11DisplayOffset 10                                                                                                                                 
PrintMotd no                                                                                                                                        
PrintLastLog yes                                                                                                                                    
TCPKeepAlive yes                                                                                                                                    
#UseLogin no                                                                                                                                        

#MaxStartups 10:30:60                                                                                                                               
Banner /etc/issue.net                                                                                                                               

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables                                                                                                 
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*                                                                                                                                 

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server                                                                                                         

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,                                                                               
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will                                                                               
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and                                                                                        
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,                                                                                     
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass                                                                                 
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".                                                                                                
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without                                                                                
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication                                                                               
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.                                                                                                      
UsePAM no
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar to this? Also if so, how did you fix it?

Requested information:

```
ls -al /root/.ssh
total 24
drwx------  2 root root 4096 May 16 04:32 .
drwx------ 19 root root 4096 Aug  1 09:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  403 Apr 29 02:00 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root root 1679 Aug  1 12:25 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  396 Aug  1 12:25 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  888 Jul 29 08:02 known_hosts      

passwd -S root
root L 05/25/2018 0 99999 7 -1

pam_tally2 --user=root
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
root                0    

ssh -v -p50683 10.0.1.41
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.41 [10.0.1.41] port 50683.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.1.41:50683 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:haAvEjO8pjy5QKLsGPAKqQe3n2AUKb3L5gRt0obkImI
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '10.0.1.41' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Your PAM confg probably contains pam_tally and somebody probably triggered it for root. Run `pam_tally2 --user=root` or try `pam_tally2 --user=root --reset`

Comment: @MarkWagner 0 failures.

Comment: @MarkWagner craziest part is that rsync still works too.

Comment: Is rsync also using that non-default port? What does "passwd -S root" say? is the root account really "locked"? Are the permissions on the root home dir, .ssh dir and files right? ssh is very picky about those.

Comment: @rems everything is correct. I was ssh'd in last night. the only port available for ssh is 50683, so yes rsync uses it as well.

Comment: well, something seems to have changed from "last night" to today. Are you the only user with root access on that server? Are updates being installed automatically? Can you post the output of "passwd -S root" and "ls -al /root/.ssh" ? More eyes see more. :)

Comment: Have you checked the output of "ssh -v ..." for any hints or issues?

Comment: @rems requested information has been added to the question at the bottom. I'll run ssh -v right now and post that as well

Comment: What about "cat -A /root/.ssh/authorized_keys" ? Any control characters in there? I wonder why your root account shows as locked. Can you retry unlocking it?

Comment: On which server?

Comment: On the server where you are trying to ssh into, 10.0.1.41, of course. I hope all other info is from that server, or not? Or are we mixing data from different "servers" ?

Comment: @rems well regenerating the ssh keys again worked successfully for some reason. Appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by regenerating keys again. Don't know why that worked the second time, but it did.

- Regenerate keys
- Restart SSH
- Login

Comment: Restarting ssh is not needed if you are regenerating the user keys. Had you perhaps added some extra character or was some character missing in the previous authorized_keys file? We probably will never know now ... :)

Comment: That’s a strong possibility! Thanks again